# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) with sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: linux, generics, sudo, apt-get

Observing following error with sudo apt-get -f install

Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic

Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin

run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 exited with return code 10

Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic.postrm line 330.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic (--remove):

subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:

linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic

linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic

linux-image-extra-4.4.0-130-generic

linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic

linux-image-extra-4.4.0-133-generic

linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic

linux-image-extra-4.4.0-134-generic

linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

=======

Comment: This is off topic, better try your luck on a Linux / Debian / Ubuntu site